# Trying to make submission (587) work - Exchange 2016

Tags: exchange, email-server, smtp-auth, starttls

I'm trying to allow the authenticated relay (Client Frontend connector) to process requests from LAN and internet, but I'm struggling so far.

First, I have linked this connector to my SSL wildcard certificate (so far so good, openssl starttls on 587 OK)

Then, when I execute an SMTP diag on port 587 from the LAN with a mailbox account, I get :

```
Error: SMTP protocol error. 504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type.

Failed to send message
```

So, I disabled "offer basic authentication only after starting tls" in the ECP, and it's working a little better, but I'm not OK with that because, I want the connections from the internet to be secured.

Furthermore, It still doesn't work because now, I get the following message :

```
Error: SMTP protocol error. 550 5.7.60 SMTP; Client does not have permissions to send as this sender.

Failed to send message
```

I'm using the same email in the from field as the one from the mailbox account I'm filling the credentials in.

Any help appreciated, regards

Answer (score 0):

Which permission group are you select on this receive connector?
Ensure "Anonymous users" is checked.

[image]